# What's the default search path for find_package(<package>) function while using cmake?

Tags: cmake

I would also like to know the default variables which are set when `find_package(<package>)` finds `<package>` in Linux (Ubuntu) ?

Answer (score 11):

**Turning my comment into an answer**

If you have to melt it down the "single most important" path it would be [CMake's own module path](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Modules) containing pre-shipped `Find...` modules.

The most important global variable variable to point CMake to custom paths would be [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html).

If you want to see which directories CMake is search in your case just call

```
 cmake -D CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON ..
```

The whole "search algorithm" is documented in [`find_package()` command documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html):

> 1. Search paths specified in cmake-specific cache variables. This can be skipped if `NO_CMAKE_PATH` is passed:
>
>    ```
>    CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
>    CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH
>    CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH
>    ```
> 2. Search paths specified in cmake-specific environment variables. This can be skipped if `NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` is passed:
>
>    ```
>    <package>_DIR
>    CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
>    CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH
>    CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH
>    ```
> 3. Search paths specified by the `HINTS` option. Hard-coded guesses should be specified with the `PATHS` option.
> 4. Search the standard system environment variables. This can be skipped if `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` is passed:
>
>    ```
>    PATH
>    ```
> 5. Search paths stored in the CMake User Package Registry. This can be skipped if `NO_CMAKE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY` is passed or by setting the `CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY` to `TRUE`.
> 6. Search cmake variables defined in the Platform files for the current system. This can be skipped if `NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH` is passed:
>
>    ```
>    CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH
>    CMAKE_SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_PATH
>    CMAKE_SYSTEM_APPBUNDLE_PATH
>    ```
> 7. Search paths stored in the CMake System Package Registry. This can be skipped if `NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY` is passed or by setting the `CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY` to `TRUE`.
> 8. Search paths specified by the `PATHS` option. These are typically hard-coded guesses.